# A Web ssh/telnet client

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, apache-httpd

I'm in kind of a tight spot right now. I wanted to know if someone has seen a HTML, or PHP web ssh client as both my company and school block everything besides port 80. I'm a control freak when it comes to my servers so yah.
I have found things like gateone but here's specifically my issue.

I have access via port 80.
I host websites on port 80 if my server.
I can run PHP scripts via Apache.
I cannot visit sites via encryption.
I cannot change the ssh port (trust me, I've tried)
I have root access to the server.

Any help or Ideas would be appreciated. If worse comes to worse, I can write my own in PHP.

Comment: A [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=web+ssh) brings up quite a few interesting projects. Have you tried any?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [Shell in a Box](https://code.google.com/p/shellinabox/), [Gate One](http://liftoffsoftware.com/Products/GateOne) or [Commando](https://github.com/nodesocket/commando) do what you want, but you might need to configure them to disable encryption:

> Shell In A Box implements a web server that can export arbitrary command line tools to a web based terminal emulator. This emulator is accessible to any JavaScript and CSS enabled web browser and does not require any additional browser plugins. Most typically, login shells would be exported this way:

---

> Gate One™ is a web-based Terminal Emulator and SSH client that brings the power of the command line to the web. It requires no browser plugins and is built on top of a powerful plugin system that allows every aspect of its appearance and functionality to be customized.

---

> Commando.io is a web-based interface for streamlining the use of SSH for deployments and system administration tasks across groups of remote servers.

Answer (score 0):

You could run [Ajaxterm](http://antony.lesuisse.org/software/ajaxterm/) on your server (you'd have to run a web server there). Ajaxterm is a web application that gives you a terminal inside a browser. It's ok for typing commands, it sucks for transferring files. There's an [Ubuntu package](http://packages.ubuntu.com/ajaxterm) and an [Ubuntu community page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AjaxTerm).

Answer (score 0):

[httptunnel](http://www.nocrew.org/software/httptunnel.html) allows you to tunnel a connection over `HTTP PUT` requests. So you could use ssh on top of that (for instance with it's `ProxyCommand`), then you wouldn't have to sacrifice encryption or server/client authentication.